# Spring - adding css to webapp

Tags: css, spring, web-applications, java-8, tomcat8

I know this is a commonly asked question, have read few topics here about that but even with advices there I wasnt able to load .css files propely.

My project directory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSgwX.png
css files path: `webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css/`

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mobilenet.website</groupId>
  <artifactId>website</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mobilenet</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    </properties>


  <dependencies>
   <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mobilenet.website" />

    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"  
    cache-period="31556926"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>mobilenet</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

 </web-app>
```

Index.jsp

```
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Modern Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="<c:url value="/css/modern-business.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

I've ran out of ideas, please lend me your wisdom.

Comment: And you happily forget to add the web page that includes the css.

Comment: Added, sorry @M.Deinum

Comment: And when you display your page in browser, what do you see in the generated source code? does your link tags contain the correctly generated links? If so, did you tried to access the css from the browser, is it loading?

Comment: Nop, css is not loading. Direct link to css file is 404.

Comment: You have 3 different ways of loading 2 of which definitely will not work. Also putting a tsp tag inside "" will not work in general.

Comment: @M.Deinum It doesn't matter that those css in index.jsp are defined wrong. Still direct link doesn't have those css(in war file they are).

Comment: Which direct link.. What are you trying, those in your jsp will simply never work.

Comment: It's working now, @M.Deinum your advice helped a lot, thanks.